# FSM framework required

Tags: finite-automata, state-machine

Please recommend framework for Finite State Machine creation and simulation. I am aware of Stateflow package in Matlab, but are there any other good choices? It shouldn't be only Matlab. Frameworks on Java, R or Python are also ok.

What I am basically trying to do is to evolve automata for binary sequence prediction problem, like shown in [this article](http://www.biocut.unito.it/giacobini/files/ea01_prediction.pdf)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider [Ragel](http://www.complang.org/ragel/). It has a manual and a good amount of examples; I find the documentation superior to that of [AT&T Research's FSM Tools](http://www2.research.att.com/~fsmtools/fsm/) (which consisted of a couple manpages and sparse examples).

Comment: Thanks it looks like exactly what I was looking for. Simple to use and has all required features.